# How to filter pull requests and issues by username on GitHub

Tags: github

Having looked around on various sites, I cannot find a tag for filtering pull requests / issues by username.

I followed this [GitHub article](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-users/), but this did not fix my issue.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-by-the-author-of-an-issue-or-pull-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter it using `author:username`